# How to make IntelliJ IDEA auto inject 'use strict'; to each new JavaScript file I create?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I have Prefer strict mode enabled, so IDEA injects 'use strict'; into functions. But why not inject it as the first line in my file?

Is there any problem with it? If no - how to tell IDEA to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own [image: File and Code Templates] like I did here. It will appear inside the File.

Here's how it looks like: [image: New File]

It initially didn't show up, but after restart I could see the new file type.